# fireCMS how to add collection length to the name of collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm not good at React, how can I add the length of collection to the name of the collection, for example it would turn out like this "Users - 21"

```
      collections: [
        buildCollection({
          path: "users",
          schema: usersSchema,
          name: "Users",
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is added by default in the latest 2.0.0-alpha versions ;)